# Creating list of usernames from User model in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

Im trying to make a user list for my multiselectfield.

```
class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        users = User.objects.values_list('id','username')
        authorized = MultiSelectField(choices=users, null=True)
```

but the problem is that later on in my html file i can't compare those values with a logged user id

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
  <ul>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        {% for person in question.authorized %}
            {% ifequal person request.user.id %}
            <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: here's my traceback calls after use only() instead of values_list():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ab/Documents/szkieletowe/projectmaster/DjangoPollsApp/PollsApp/polls/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "/home/ab/Documents/szkieletowe/projectmaster/DjangoPollsApp/PollsApp/polls/models.py", line 12, in Question
    authorized = MultiSelectField(choices=users, null=True)
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiselectfield/db/fields.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.max_length = get_max_length(self.choices, self.max_length)
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiselectfield/utils.py", line 31, in get_max_length
    return len(','.join([string_type(key) for key, label in choices]))
  File "/home/ab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiselectfield/utils.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    return len(','.join([string_type(key) for key, label in choices]))
TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable
```

and my views.py:

```
class VotesView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/votes.html'
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```

Comment: `{% ifequal person request.user.id %}` person is person (id) ? what is person can you tell? or person is object, and you need to put `person.id`

Comment: for now after runserver person is just id, but comparison between person and request.user.id or request.user not working. So im looking for any clues for it

Comment: you wrote that you can't compare thos values, can you explain that , what do you mean

Comment: What is MultiSelectField? Sounds like a form widget rather than a model field. Where is it defined? How are you populating it in your Question model?

Comment: i meant that comparison always return false

Answer (score 0):

```
class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        users = User.objects.values_list('id','username')
        authorized = MultiSelectField(choices=users, null=True)
```

**edit**

I have changed `only` to `values_list` again, i got it you are populating all the users id and username and storing them as tuple to make a choice list.

now in your template  you should do like this

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
  <ul>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        {% for person in question.authorized %}
            {% ifequal person request.user.username %}
            <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: i get: TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable

Comment: Yeah, so that is something new now maybe because you are not passing a list to template, can you please post complete traceback and view code ?

Comment: thanks, {% ifequal person request.user.username %} returns false even if i change for request.user.id.  For your information <li>person </li> return only id of authorized users. idk what to do..

Comment: if you are sure  <li>{{person}} </li> is returning id, if so then it should work as expected with {{request.user.id}}

Comment: i know but its not working. I tried to create variables in django template language and then compare them but still same - comparison always return false

Comment: i think that i need to find other way to create multiselectfield with checkboxes